# Can I disable the redo log for a DELETE query or a whole transaction?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6, transaction-log

I'm working on an existing database, whose structure I can't change. I need to clear (empty) several InnoDB tables (that I can't `TRUNCATE` due to references in other tables' FK constraints), but I have no interest in any recovery - i.e. if a crash occurs during those operations, I'll clear those tables again on the first occasion.

Can I tell MySQL to not create the redo log about those queries?

I am concerned about speed, as the first thing that can be noted is the time the operation takes. But, space too, I guess. Tables can store 20k-1M rows depending on the specific installation (same schema structure, different usages). I am operating on a bunch of table whose data are related (i.e. products, products_images, products_votes, ...), so FK are not an issue because all data will be deleted consistently without the need of any additional check.

Comment: So, all the tables that have FKs that reference this table will be emptied too, correct? So, a DELETE will succeed due to ON DELETE CASCADE actions you have specified in the FKs. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, the problem is:

We have one or more tables (lets call them "parents") that we want to empty, either with `DELETE` or `TRUNCATE`. There are several other tables ("children") that have `FOREING KEY` constraints which reference the first table(s) or some other "child" and we want to empty those tables as well.

- If we `DELETE`, the operation will succeed, as all the FKs have been defined with `ON DELETE CASCADE` actions. But it will be a very slow operation.
- If we `TRUNCATE`, the operation fails due to the FKs. It's not allowed to `TRUNCATE` a table that other tables reference it.

To solve this conundrum, I don't think that messing with the redo log is advisable (if at all possible).

I suggest the more simple:

- `ALTER` the children tables and `DROP` the offending `FOREIGN KEY` constraints.
- `TRUNCATE` all the tables.
- `ALTER` the children tables and add the constraints again.

If some reason altering the tables even temporarily is forbidden, you should at least follow MySQL's guidelines about optimizing the redo logs: [Optimizing InnoDB Redo Logging](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb-logging.html)